# How to use hogcomparator in java code for checking face similarity?

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I'm working on a java program to compare the faces of image to check whether same person in both images and I found out that it is pretty much accurate if I use `hogcomparator`. So my function is like below,

```
public class CompareFaces {

    static {
        nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
        System.loadLibrary("hogcomparator");
    }

    private native boolean compare(long addr1, long addr2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Mat phoMat1 = imread("D:\\projects\\face_recognition\\images\\one");
            Mat phoMat2 = imread("D:\\projects\\face_recognition\\images\\two");

            CompareFaces cf = new CompareFaces();
            System.out.println("Images are from same person?" + cf.compare(phoMat1.getNativeObjAddr(), phoMat2.getNativeObjAddr()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("some thing not fine");
        }
    }}
```

I have configured opencv correctly but when I ran this program it says that

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hogcomparator in java.library.path

So is there any thing I must do before using hogcomparator?
Or other way which can achieve this thing will be helpfull.